# AutoMapper: Direct Mapping to Sub-Object Destination Fields Not Working as Expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I’m seeing some odd behavior with AutoMapper, where I can’t directly map source and destination fields, when the destination field is in a sub-object. Instead, I need to wrap the source field in a method call, which checks if the field is null. If it is not null, it returns the value otherwise it returns null. It doesn’t seem right to have to do that. Especially since mapping to destination fields on the root object works without need of this hack.

To be fair, I’m not sure the issue is with AutoMapper. It may be that the problem lies with EntityFramework Core. But, on the surface, it looks like an AutoMapper issue.

Because of concerns about intellectual property, I can’t share the code were the issue was discovered. So, I wrote a working sample, that is as close to the original code as I could make it and which exhibits the same issue. It can be found at https://github.com/BurikkuDeibu/BrickApi. The *master* branch has the code as I think it should be. The *UseMagicMethods* branch has the code with the hacks needed to make things work. The real file of interest in the *UseMagicMethods* branch is https://github.com/BurikkuDeibu/BrickApi/blob/UseMagicMethods/src/WebApi/Models/ElementDetailsMapper.cs

From the master Branch (throws exception):

```cs
    public class ElementDetailsMapper
    {
        public class ElementDetailsProfile : Profile
        {
            public ElementDetailsProfile()
            {
                CreateMap<ElementDetailEntity, RGBDetail>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.R, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Red))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.G, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Green))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.B, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Blue));

                CreateMap<ElementDetailEntity, ColorDetail>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.RGB, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.ColorId))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Color))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.IsTranparent, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Transparent))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.IsMetaliic, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Metallic));

                CreateMap<ElementDetailEntity, DesignDetail>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.DesignId))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Design));

                CreateMap<ElementDetailEntity, ElementDetails>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Color, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Design, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.ManufactureStartDate, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.ManufactureStartDate))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.ManufactureEndDate, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.ManufactureEndDate));
            }
        }
    }
```

From the UseMagicMethods Branch (works):

```cs
        public class ElementDetailsProfile : Profile
        {
            public ElementDetailsProfile()
            {
                CreateMap<ElementDetailEntity, RGBDetail>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.R, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => ByteMagic(src.Red)))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.G, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => ByteMagic(src.Green)))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.B, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => ByteMagic(src.Blue)));

                CreateMap<ElementDetailEntity, ColorDetail>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.RGB, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => ShortMagic(src.ColorId)))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => StringMagic(src.Color)))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.IsTranparent, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => BooleanMagic(src.Transparent)))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.IsMetaliic, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => BooleanMagic(src.Metallic)));

                CreateMap<ElementDetailEntity, DesignDetail>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => StringMagic(src.DesignId)))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => StringMagic(src.Design)));

                CreateMap<ElementDetailEntity, ElementDetails>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Color, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Design, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.ManufactureStartDate, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.ManufactureStartDate))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.ManufactureEndDate, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.ManufactureEndDate));
            }

            public static bool? BooleanMagic(bool? input)
            {
                return input.HasValue ? input.Value : (bool?)null;
            }

            public static byte? ByteMagic(byte? input)
            {
                return input.HasValue ? input.Value : (byte?)null;
            }

            public static short? ShortMagic(short? input)
            {
                return input.HasValue ? input.Value : (short?)null;
            }

            public static string StringMagic(string input)
            {
                return input ?? null;
            }
        }
    }
```

You’ll notice that in that code file in the *UseMagicMethods* branch, I’ve wrapped each source field that maps to a destination sub-object field in a method call. The data types for both destination and source field match exactly, so I’d think I could directly map them. However, if I try that I get a NullReference exception with the following stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.CacheKey.<>c.<GetHashCode>b__6_0(Int32 t, TypeMaterializationInfo v)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate[TSource,TAccumulate](IEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 func)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.CacheKey.GetHashCode()
   at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1.GetHashCode(T obj)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.Create(IReadOnlyList`1 types)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Sql.Internal.FromSqlNonComposedQuerySqlGenerator.CreateValueBufferFactory(IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory relationalValueBufferFactoryFactory, DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.<NotifyReaderCreated>b__14_0(FactoryAndReader s)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.NonCapturingLazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[TParam,TValue](TValue& target, TParam param, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.NotifyReaderCreated(DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<BufferlessMoveNext>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNext>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<Aggregate_>d__6`3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at WebApi.Controllers.ElementController.<Get>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.<Execute>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

You’ll notice in the stack trace all kinds of references to EntityFramework Core, which is why I wonder if maybe the issue really lies there.

So, am I doing something wrong, or is there an issue with either AutoMapper or EntityFramework Core?

Comment: `FromSqlNonComposedQuerySqlGenerator` means the query is using client evaluation, hence `ProjectTo` (which is AM generated `Select`) has no much effect. Avoid `FromSql`, and especially with [non composable SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#composing-with-linq)

Comment: @IvanStoev So, then help me understand... Why does wrapping the source fields in method calls cause the code to start working? I would think that if the problem truly was with the client evaluation, that adding more code...which I assume would be evaluated client-side... wouldn't solve the problem. But, it does. Why?

Comment: Client evaluation is quite different from server evaluation. For instance, there are no objects, hence no null reference exceptions inside SQL. But when the expressions are evaluated locally, then of course they evaluate on real objects, so null object rules apply. I'm not saying it's your fault, EF Core client eval is unstable (has bugs) and is causing many problems, so avoiding it is the practical approach. The main idea of AM `ProjectTo` (as opposed to `Map`) is to produce server evaluatable query.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks, while I don't fully understand what's going on, your explanation has given me a greater understanding than I had when I asked the question. While not a true solution, if you'd like to post an answer re-stating what you've already said, I'll accept it.

Also, if you could remove your "Oops..." comment, that'd clean up the thread.

Comment: You are welcome, glad being a bit helpful :) I don't feel comfortable to compose an answer though, feel free to post self answer if you wish.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, replace your SP with db view and try `FromSql("select * from your_db_view")` with the broken code. IMO it should work. Cheers.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yup, you're right. It does work with a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that because I was using the *ProjectTo* method, I was dependent on what EntityFramework Core supports, in terms of translating the query. At this point, it doesn't support what I was trying to do.

...

Based on comments from above, I tried a few things.

I tried switching from *ProjectTo* to *Map*, which seems to work quite nicely. This is the method that we decided to go with, so that we could eliminate the *magic* methods.

I also tried using a view instead of a stored procedure. This also works, but it made our DBA very unhappy.

I also tried using a query type instead of an entity type for my stored procedure results. This made no difference. Without the *magic* methods, I would still get the NullReference exception.